# Return object(T) from switch statement

Tags: c#, generics

In my code I am having `ManagerService` of `T` type which can be `BaseManager` or `AnotherManager`:

```
abstract class BaseManager { }
abstract class FooManager : BaseManager { }
abstract class AnotherManager : BaseManager { }
class ManagerService<T> where T : BaseManager { }
```

Now I want to get specific object by `string`:

```
static ManagerService<T> GetService<T>(string serviceName)  where T : BaseManager
{
    switch(serviceName)
    {
        case "foo": return new ManagerService<FooManager>();
        case "another": return new ManagerService<AnotherManager>();
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("Service not found");
}
```

And here would be usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var serviceBase = GetService("foo"); // it should return ManagerService<FooManager>
    var serviceAnother = GetService("another"); // it should return ManagerService<AnotherManager>
}
```

Unfortunately that doesnt work. I am having error:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'app.ManagerService<app.FooManager>' to 'app.ManagerService<T>'`.

What is wrong there?

Comment: That someone could call `GetService<AnotherManager>("base")` and what you want to do would break type safety? In such a case, your signature promised to return a `ManagerService<AnotherManager`. That's not what your code would do.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I updated my question. So there is no way to do this? The thing is I want to have a switch statement to return object depending on string input. I am doing this several times in my code, so I dont want to duplicate this.

Answer (score 3):

When calling `GetService<T>(string serviceName)`, **the generic type `T` must be known at compile time**. Either you need to specify it when making the call, or the compiler must be able to derive it from the parameters of the method (but you have no such parameters).

You can fix that by eliminating `serviceName` and using `T` instead, like this:

```
static ManagerService<T> GetService<T>() where T : BaseManager
{
    return new ManagerService<T>();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s1 = GetService<FooManager>();     // returns ManagerService<FooManager>
    var s2 = GetService<AnotherManager>(); // returns ManagerService<AnotherManager>
}
```

If you don't know the `T`-s in advance (you only know `serviceName` at runtime) then you can use the abstract base type `BaseManager`:

```
abstract class ManagerService { }
class ManagerService<T> : ManagerService where T : BaseManager { }

static ManagerService GetService(string serviceName)
{
    switch(serviceName)
    {
        case "foo":
            return new ManagerService<FooManager>();
        case "another":
            return new ManagerService<AnotherManager>();
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("Service not found");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s1 = GetService("foo");     // returns ManagerService<FooManager> typed as ManagerService
    var s2 = GetService("another"); // returns ManagerService<AnotherManager> typed as ManagerService
}
```

Comment: I am getting `string serviceName` from database, so this is why I am passing this as a `string`.

Comment: @dafie if this won't work for you, you should take a look at the `dynamic` keyword

Comment: @dafie - but such code will not compile unless you can supply the correct type argument, `T`, at the *callsites* for the `GetService` method. So you still have to know what the correct type is.

Comment: I added an alternative approach using a non-generic `GetService()` method.

Comment: @PeterB I already tried this. I am getting error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'app.ManagerService<app.FooManager>' to 'app.BaseManager'
`

Comment: I improved the non-generic example, I typed a bit too fast, sorry. It now uses an abstract class ManagerService (or you could use an Interface). I ran it all through Visual Studio this time.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, as a *consumer* of generics, you should know the types you're working with at *compile* time - they're either a specific type you know and can pass directly as a generic type parameter or you're *implementing* something generic yourself and are passing through some type arguments.

You're trying to mix in runtime knowledge. This tends to be fragile even if you can make it work, and will tend to involve lots of excessive casting to "shut up" the compiler - even though it's warnings are valid and you're trading compile time safety for (possible) runtime errors.

So, if possible, try not to "defer" generic decisions until runtime. This should compile:

```
class ManagerService<T> where T : BaseManager
{

}

static ManagerService<T> GetService<T>(/* not needed? */string serviceName)  where T : BaseManager
{
    return new ManagerService<T>();
}
```

Because now we're letting the *generic* parameter determine our return type. Of course, at this point it's unclear if the string serves any purpose.

Even with your original code, you'd still have had to supply the *correct* type parameter at the callsite in order for it to compile, as you will with the above.

Answer (score 0):

Since you commented that you want to determine the type of manager based on a string you get from the database:

If you don't know the type of manager at compile time, then maybe you want to go with this [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) approach instead:

*(If this is going to work depends on how your BaseManager and ManagerService are implemented.)*

```
// common interface for all manager implementations
interface IManager
{ }

// optional: basic implementation
abstract class BaseManager : IManager
{ }

class FooManager : BaseManager
{ }

class AnotherManager : BaseManager
{ }

class ManagerService
{
    // constructor accepting the IManager implementation
    public ManagerService(IManager manager);
}

static ManagerService GetService(string serviceName)
{
    switch(serviceName)
    {
        case "foo":
            return new ManagerService(new FooManager());
        case "another":
            return new ManagerService(new AnotherManager());
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("Service not found");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var serviceBase = GetService("foo"); // Returns ManagerService using the FooManager implementation
    var serviceAnother = GetService("another"); // Returns ManagerService using the AnotherManager implementation
}
```